# Gmail/Google no longer has an "All Contacts" list?

Tags: gmail, google, google-contacts

Today I noticed that Gmail nor Google Contacts offers a way to list "All Contacts" any longer; my contacts are now split between the groups I made and "Other Contacts".

Is there any way to list all my contacts in one place that I'm not aware of?

---

Although "Basic HTML" still has the All Contacts list, it doesn't offer any means to merge/organize the contacts.

Comment: I find this annoying too.  I recently imported all my phone contacts, and they show up in "My Contacts" but most of the email addresses are in "other contacts" and I can't figure out how to merge contacts from each of the 2 groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on `My contacts` to see all of your contacts at once.

GMail link: http://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts
Google Contacts link: http://www.google.com/contacts_v2/u/0/#contacts

`Other Contacts` still contain the auto-created records of people with whom you exchanged only a few messages and they have never been included in `All Contacts`.

Comment: So is there any way to show both of them in one place? I regularly  have duplicates between these two groups and no practical way of merging them.

Comment: Go through "Other Contacts" deleting everyone you don't need and moving everyone you need into "My Contacts", then check for duplicates.

Comment: Actually, there did use to be an All Contacts section, as visible in the "older version". Using the above method to organize my contact was satisfactory however, so after all this time, I'll accept.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think I could view them in gmail anymore, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you fix this:

- Select all of the contacts in the list that's not showing up in "My Contacts".  You can do this by selecting the check box at the tip of the contact list.
- Select the "groups" button, which has an image of several stick figure people.  (It's not labeled.)
- Check the lists you'd like these people to be in and uncheck the ones you don't.
- When your list is empty, you can delete it.

Basically, you have to manually combine all of theses lists together into one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to clean up contacts:

1. Export the contacts to a .csv file
2. Delete all contacts and groups
3. Edit the .csv file by putting "My Contacts" in the "Group Membership" column
4. Import the modified .csv file

   - This loads the contacts to "My Contacts" and an "imported..." group
5. Delete the "imported..." group

You will now have all your contacts in "My Contacts".

Answer (score 0):

found it, this fixes the problem.

On the bottom of the page, click 'older version'.

This will allow you to select All Contacts. Bingo!

Then if you want, you can select All Contacts in the older version and add them to "My Contacts" group so that they will be viewable in the new version as well.

Answer (score -1):

You have to open *Contact* link given in Gmail and then click on *"All Contacts"*. Here, you can see a list of all your contacts. If any problems occur then you just need to use Gmail in *Basic HTML* view. I am sure you will get an all contact list.

There is not any effective feature available in Gmail to effectively merge contact list.

Answer (score -2):

Just try **My Contacts** in **Basic HTML View**, that should help.